# React Native App no longer builds after upgrading to XCode12.5

Tags: xcode, react-native, xcode12

My react native app previously built and ran on a simulator in xcode 11. However since upgrading to xcode 12.5 I get the following build errors

```
Cannot initialize a parameter of type 'NSArray<id<RCTBridgeModule>> *' with an rvalue of type 'NSArray<Class>*'

Cannot initialize a parameter of type 'NSArray<Class> *' with an lvalue of type 'NSArray<id<RCTBridgeModule>> *__strong'

Cannot initialize a parameter of type 'NSArray<id<RCTBridgeModule>> *' with an lvalue of type 'NSArray<Class> *__strong'
```

These errors come from react-core which is in my project via cocoapods.

Comment: Fixed using https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/28405#issuecomment-779382959

Answer (score 6):

Change `RCTCxxBridge.mm` 624 line

```
Code Block Objective-C
NSArray<id<RCTBridgeModule>> *)modules
```

to

```
Code Block Objective-C
NSArray<Class> *)modules
```